# C# Serilog, how to save Log to a different sink after events occured?

Tags: c#, serilog

Is there a possibility to copy the contents of a Logfile (ex. InMemorySink) into an other logfile?

I want to create a temporary logger for each UI-Thread that records verbose information about user interactions and whatnot. My intention is that I can dump all the logged content into the mainlogger in case the window crashes.